# Files inside TVMLKit.framework

Tags: tvos, tvml

Is there any way to view the files and code that belong to TVMLKit.framework*?

*[TVMLKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvmlkit) is a framework from Apple to build tvOS Apps:

> The TVMLKit framework enables you to evaluate TVMLKit JS and TVML files from within your tvOS app. You can create TVML elements, styles, views, and view controllers through the JavaScript environment.

I'm trying to create new elements by using TVInterfaceFactory and would like to see how some of the base elements are made in order to duplicate some of them and make small changes.

I can't seem to find these files in Xcode or the project folder. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You can only view header files in frameworks.

Comment: So no way to see m or swift files? No way to actually see the code behind the framework?